# If $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, is $f':\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it true that if $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, then its derivative function is also holomorphic?

How can it be proved? In case this is true.

Thanks.

Comment: It's true. You can prove it by Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Complex analysis can be developed from wildly different starting points. The result you mention can be proved in different ways, but some may not be useful to you, depending on what your definition is of "holomorphic". Is it through the Cauchy-Riemann equations? Through the C-R equations, plus a continuity assumption? Through local power series? Through complex differentiation?

Comment: @DanielFischer and Andres, I can use Cauchy's integral formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use Cauchy's integral formula, consider a $z_0$ in the domain of definition of $f$, and a disk $D_{3r}(z_0) = \{ z : \lvert z - z_0\rvert < 3r\}$ that is contained in the domain. Then, for $z \in D_r(z_0)$, we have the representation

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_{2r}(z_0)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z}\,d\zeta.\tag{1}$$

For $z \in D_r(z_0)$ (actually, $z\in D_{2r}(z_0)$, but let's stay far enough away from the contour to have a uniform bound for the integrand), you can differentiate under the integral by the dominated convergence theorem, and differentiating yields

$$f'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial D_{2r}(z_0)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2}\,d\zeta,$$

which can again be differentiated under the integral. Etc. ad infinitum.

Alternatively, we can develop the integrand in $(1)$ into a geometric series,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\zeta - z} &= \frac{1}{\zeta-z_0}\cdot \frac{1}{1- \frac{z-z_0}{\zeta-z_0}}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z-z_0)^n}{(\zeta-z_0)^{n+1}}.
\end{align}$$

Since the series converges uniformly on the contour, and $f$ is bounded on it, we can interchange integration and summation, so

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_{2r}(z_0)} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^{n+1}}\,d\zeta \right)(z-z_0)^n\tag{2}$$

and the power series $(2)$ can be differentiated arbitrarily often by general considerations about power series.